# Multiple WSDL definitions in the same namespace

Tags: wsdl, soa, xml-namespaces

On the project I am working on, we are defining multiple WSDLs in the same target namespace. (That is each WSDL definition has a different name attribute but they share a common namespace).

The SOA guys here are saying they need each WSDL definition in its own namespace. (Looks like some technical constraint in their software or bug; I am not sure).

My understanding is that having multiple WSDL definitions in the same namespace is not illegal. Can anyone confirm or deny this and perhaps point to relevant standards documentation that will support it?

**UPDATE:**

After reading a little more, it seems (for example from the [WSDL 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl)) that while referring to various schemas that are all part of the same target namespace is OK, the examples that I see of WSDL definition target namespaces indicate a unique namespace per WSDL definition, but I wonder if this ends up being a matter of interpretation, as I find no official directive saying you must have each WSDL definition in its own namespace.

What is the general consensus out there? What examples have you seen in the wild? Do you ever create multiple WSDL definitions in the same namespace? I would be interested to hear your input.

Just for reference, I am working with SAP software and they use namespaces to reflect a software component/version or solution, thereby having many WSDL definitions in a common namespace. Guys from SOA.com, on the other hand, seem to be of the opinion that each WSDL definition must have its own namespace.

Comment: SAP and SOA from my experience has always been a bit of a red headed step child. I prefer the option of each WSDL having its own name space. The reason being that a WSDL should only model one atomic service such as a customer or a ledger etc. Its is really more a SOA governance issue this though.

Comment: @Namphibian And what with a situation where there are multiple service providers that have exactly same service, same WSDL (so basically one service/WSDL deployed on multiple addresses) with clients connecting to more then one service provider.
Should/Can such WSDL's share the same namespace or should each service provider use their own namespace?

Comment: A name space is like packages in java and .net in a sense that they identify the various bit and pieces that make up a web service. If this service is deployed in more than one location I dont see a problem really. However if the same namespaces reffer to different xsd schemas for examples it might be a class A military screw up.  From my experience namespace normally contained a version number as well as this helped with versioning but then again your SOA governance policies might differ here.